# How I Do SQL Server Data Type Money in Digit 0.00

Tags: sql-server

I have used this code, and I need it to show values like `0.00` but right now it is showing them like `0.0000`; I do not need the extra two `00` in my display.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_28]
(
    [C1] [MONEY] NULL,
    [C2] [MONEY] NULL,
    [C3] AS ([C1] + [C2])
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Formatting the money value from display purposes should be done in the app presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP2AU.jpg)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_9](
    [C1] [decimal](38, 2) NULL,
    [C2] [decimal](38, 2) NULL,
    [C3]  AS ([C1]+[C2])
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```